# how to change the color of the placeholder of the input in html

Tags: html

I would like to change the color of the placeholder of my textfield. Here is my code. Thanks in advance

```
<input type="text" placeholder="input here"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is jsFiddle for you. [Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/Sk8erPeter/KyVXK/)

You can use following css to implement the same

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
  color:    #909;
}
:-moz-placeholder {
  color:    #999;
}
::-moz-placeholder {
  color:    #999;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color:    #999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use style to change the color of placeholder.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="input here" />
```

Then in your css write-

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
    color:    Red;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
    color:    Red;
    opacity:  1;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
    color:   Red;
    opacity:  1;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
    color:    Red;
}
```

See the output in http://jsfiddle.net/w1wjo6q4/1/
Thanks & Regards